# middleware for every user defined alias/bash function used on command line; Mac/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, bash

I have a task that is assisting my scripting...it requires counting the amount of times I use each user defined command in .bash_profile. In other words, if I run on command like something defined as an alias like `pip2install arg1 arg2`, I need to count that I ran `pip2install`.

Is there a way in linux machines to run a command before any shell script/alias/bash function runs? Like a config file where this can be defined?

I'm OK with counting how many times I run ALL commands (since I can just choose to ignore builtin commands once the UI is built)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash You can set the PROMPT_COMMAND environment variable to a command that is executed before displaying the command prompt (so, at the end of the execution of the previous command, for synchronous commands). See [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html). For instance try:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo This is displayed before your prompt"
```

Comment: so from here I just parse the last history command and run the script to write to db?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. But if you just rely on bash_history, you can just use that file once at the end of the day....  (after closing all the terminal windows).